# How to make Alexa speak phone number

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I want Alexa to say phone number as digits not as its value.

Ex:

> [Alexa] the contact number is 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0.

But now Alexa says as

> the contact number is nine billion eight hundred seventy six million
>   five hundred forty three thousand two hundred ten

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `interpret-as="telephone"` attribute of  `say-as` tag of SSML to interpret the number as a telephone number.

Ex:

```
<speak>
    the contact number is <say-as interpret-as="telephone"> 9876-543-210 </say-as>
</speak>
```

`interpret-as="telephone"` will interpret a value as a 7-digit or 10-digit telephone number. This can also handle extensions (for example, 2025551212x345).

It's always a good idea to include "-" in between phone number to give breaks  while saying the digits.

More on SSML [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html)